# WS-SecurityPolicy configuration of CXF client

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, ws-security

The question: Can CXF automatically configure WS-Security for a client based on a WS-SecurityPolicy file?

If so, is there any documentation on actually doing so? I've spent several hours looking at the CXF site and doing searches without finding an answer.

The [CXF documentation](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html) says *"CXF 2.2 introduced support for using WS-SecurityPolicy to configure WSS4J instead of the custom configuration documented on the WS-Security page"*, and also says *"In CXF 2.2, if the cxf-rt-ws-policy and cxf-rt-ws-security modules are available on the classpath, the WS-SecurityPolicy stuff is automatically enabled."* Finally, there's a listing of the properties that may need to be configured (keystore locations, etc). All of that I understand, but the documentation doesn't actually explain what enabling WS-SecurityPolicy *does*. Is it just for policy generation, or does it actually help configure clients?

---

The reason I'm asking is that I'm working on an application that uses CXF (JAX-WS front end) via Camel to consume a SOAP service secured with WS-Security. Because of the existing structure of our application, I've been trying to configure the client with WSS4J interceptors, but have been having a tough time actually implementing what they've described.

After a couple of days working on this, the provider mentioned that they had a WS-SecurityPolicy file they could send to me (why they didn't mention this up front is a mystery). Now that I have their policy, I'd really like to figure out a less code-driven way of configuring the security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a WS-SecurityPolicy configures "most" of the security requirements for a client. You still need to specify JAX-WS properties to configure users, passwords, keys etc. I would recommend checking out the CXF source and looking at the systests/ws-security-examples tests.

Comment: I understood that I'd have to provide external values as you mentioned. Have you actually used a policy to configure a client? And the only documentation you found was in the source?

Comment: I was just cleaning up the huge browser tab collection I've had open for a few days and realized a site from which I got a lot of help on WSS4j was your blog (http://coheigea.blogspot.com/2013/03/signature-and-encryption-key.html). Anyway, I went digging into the test examples and found everything I need. Thanks!